# Access on UserDevice sObject

Tags: security, sobject, spring21

I am trying to query on UserDevice sObject but in the documentation it is mentioned "You must have View Devices enabled to see devices.". So can anyone please tell me how to do this to be able to query on this object. Currently workbench gives error as not supported object

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userdevice.htm

Comment: What Salesforce edition are you using? This feature is only available in Essentials, Group, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, Developer, and Contact Manager.

Comment: Tried on unlimited edition

Comment: Are you able to find View Devices and Manage Devices checkbox on user profiles?

Comment: Did you enable the View Devices permission in your profile or permission set?

Comment: I am not seeing any view device permission in my profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to contact Salesforce to have the Mobile Device Tracking feature enabled. After that is completed, you'll need to setup permissions for View Devices and Manage Devices as you see fit (I lumped them into a perm set).

reference info here:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_device_management.htm&type=5